# Handling complex hashes in perl

Tags: perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

I have simple perl script as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my %x;

$x{"a"}="b";
$x{"b"}={'c'=>3,'d'=>4};
$x{"c"}={'e'=>{'f'=>5,'g'=>6},'h'=>{'i'=>7,'j'=>8}};

print Dumper(%x);
```

This is outputting me as below:

```
> ./temp.pl
$VAR1 = 'c';
$VAR2 = {
          'e' => {
                   'g' => 6,
                   'f' => 5
                 },
          'h' => {
                   'j' => 8,
                   'i' => 7
                 }
        };
$VAR3 = 'a';
$VAR4 = 'b';
$VAR5 = 'b';
$VAR6 = {
          'c' => 3,
          'd' => 4
        };
,
```

But my desired ouput is something different.so i tried the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my %x;

$x{"a"}="b";
$x{"b"}={'c'=>3,'d'=>4};
$x{"c"}={'e'=>{'f'=>5,'g'=>6},'h'=>{'i'=>7,'j'=>8}};

foreach (keys %x )
{
        if(ref($x{$_}) eq "HASH")
        {
        print Dumper(\%{$x{$_}}).",";
        }
        else
        {
        print $x{$_}.",\n"
        }
}
```

But this gives me an output as below:

```
> ./temp.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'e' => {
                   'g' => 6,
                   'f' => 5
                 },
          'h' => {
                   'j' => 8,
                   'i' => 7
                 }
        };
,b,
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => 3,
          'd' => 4
        };
```

but what i need is as below.i donot need VAR1 etc and also `=>` in the output.I just need the keys and values with a space in between them

```
c  {
          'e'  {
                   'g'  6,
                   'f'  5
                 },
          'h'  {
                   'j'  8,
                   'i'  7
                 }
        },
a b,
b  {
          'c'  3,
          'd'  4
        }
```

All perl experts out there ,could anybody give me the right direction to print the output as i need it!

i got what i needed from perleone's suggestion.
but i also tried the below staement:

```
my %y={"one"=>404,"two"=>\%x};
```

now if i do

```
print Dumper(\%y);
```

it gives me an output of :

```
> ./temp.pl
{
          'HASH(0x807f08c)' undef
        }
```

where did i go wrong here?

Comment: You would have to write a sub able to recursively dump the keys/values of a hash in your preferred format. It may be pretty simple using `keys` to get all the keys of a hash and `ref` to find out when some value is also hash (then you will have to recurse) or a scalar. Read `perlfunc(1)` for the details.

Comment: You know your first example is wrong. You should pass a reference to Dumper: `print Dumper(\%x)`. You should look up the documentation for Data::Dumper and see what options it offers.

Comment: OK ..i got it.Thanks TLP.Please see my edit

Comment: `my %y={"one"=>404,"two"=>\%x};` is wrong, use `()` for hashes instead of `{}`.

Comment: Oh..Yes ...sorry for my lehman's knowledge in perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods). Use these settings:

```
$Data::Dumper::Pair     = ' ';
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse    = 1;

...

print Dumper( \%x );
```

Comment: Thanks Perleone...you made me more good n perl by letting me know better things in it.